# C# Sqlite как работать с таблицами

Tags: php, c#, sqlite

C# каждый раз при запуске программы создавать таблицу? Приведу аналогию при работе с PHP(ReadBeen), когда сделать запись в таблицу, будто создаешь таблицу всегда заново, и уже потом считываешь(нашёл это в туториале по которому работал) Меня интересовало насколько это костыль. Вот этот код:

```js
$message = R::dispense('messages');
$message -> arg == "lol";
R::store($message);
```

И это работало. Теперь я работаю с C# SQlite, и вопрос как при записи в таблицу иницилизировать её. Пример как я хочу сделать:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Это будет правильно? Или же всё же надо проверять создана ли таблица и подключатся к ней по другому?

P.S не могу вставить код в сообщение ругается на табуляцию

Comment: В принципе, это нормально. Если же тебя сильно смущает, то сделай запрос, существует ли такая таблица.

Comment: @SergeyK. Хорошо, спасибо

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS - достаточно, ничего проверять не надо, после выполнения этого запроса таблица гарантированно существует (или запрос приведёт к ошибке, не связанной с таблицей - и это совсем другая сказка). Но ещё после этого надо, наверн7ое, безусловно почистить таблицу (TRUNCATE TABLE) - свежесозданной это не повредит, а существующую очистит от старых данных.

Comment: @Akina, Едва ли стоит выполнять транкейт при запуске приложения))

Comment: @SergeyK. А если в таблице останутся "сопли" от предыдущего запуска? во счастье-то - гадать, откуда и каким ветром лишние данные надуло...

Comment: @Akina, не совсем понятна логика. Какие такие сопли? База данных нужна как раз для того, чтобы данные хранить вне зависимости от работы приложения, а если их чистить, то зачем вовсе подрубать постоянное хранилище?

Comment: @SergeyK. Автор спрашивает "C# каждый раз при запуске программы создавать таблицу?". Это однозначно говорит о том, что он в принципе не рассчитывает на какие-то данные от предыдущих запусков. *зачем вовсе подрубать постоянное хранилище?* Порой запрос на SQLite куда как проще, чем крутить массивы в коде для достижения того же результата. Порой данных надо прожевать столько, что памяти надо больно дофига. В общем, это вполне обычная ситуация, когда нет данных с предыдущего запуска.

Comment: @Akina, понимать эту формулировку вопроса можно по-разному, согласен, но, я полагаю, что суть вопроса в том, что нормально ли говорить при каждом запуске CREATE IF NOT EXIST

Comment: @SergeyK. Ааа... ну в такой формулировке да. Вполне нормально. Какой смысл вертеть дополнительный запрос на проверку наличия таблицы? один запрос всяко придётся сделать, а если таблицы нет - то с проверкой получится уже два запроса.

Comment: Для данных, используемых только в рамках одной сессии приложения, внешняя БД не нужна.

Comment: Какая вообще конечная цель?

Comment: Всё таки я остановился на проверке запроса о выборке таблице, моя конечная цель всегда иметь таблицу и записывать в неё, если же таблица существует, мне её не надо очищать, я просто "дозаписываю" данные в неё